# SSH into EC2 through AWS Lambda using paramiko library

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, ssh, paramiko

I want to SSH into EC2 instance through Lambda function, I have created a layer for paramiko library. The lambda function picks up the library but it gives me this error:

```
Response
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.ExitError",
  "errorMessage": "RequestId: 26d4c295-51f8-4d98-b698-277a3e43336d Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1"
}

Function Logs
ACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/runtime/bootstrap.py", line 480, in <module>
main()
File "/var/runtime/bootstrap.py", line 452, in main
request_handler = _get_handler(handler)
File "/var/runtime/bootstrap.py", line 46, in _get_handler
m = imp.load_module(modname, file_handle, pathname, desc)
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 234, in load_module
return load_source(name, filename, file)
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
module = _load(spec)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 702, in _load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 3, in <module>
import paramiko
File "/opt/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
from paramiko.transport import (
File "/opt/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 33, in <module>
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import algorithms, Cipher, modes
File "/opt/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers.base import (
File "/opt/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/base.py", line 10, in <module>
from cryptography.exceptions import (
File "/opt/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cryptography/exceptions.py", line 9, in <module>
from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._rust import exceptions as rust_exceptions
pyo3_runtime.PanicException: Python API call failed
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_cffi_backend'
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'Python API call failed', /github/home/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/pyo3-0.18.3/src/err/mod.rs:790:5
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/runtime/bootstrap.py", line 480, in <module>
main()
File "/var/runtime/bootstrap.py", line 452, in main
request_handler = _get_handler(handler)
File "/var/runtime/bootstrap.py", line 46, in _get_handler
m = imp.load_module(modname, file_handle, pathname, desc)
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 234, in load_module
return load_source(name, filename, file)
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
module = _load(spec)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 702, in _load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 3, in <module>
import paramiko
File "/opt/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
from paramiko.transport import (
File "/opt/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 33, in <module>
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import algorithms, Cipher, modes
File "/opt/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers.base import (
File "/opt/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/base.py", line 10, in <module>
from cryptography.exceptions import (
File "/opt/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cryptography/exceptions.py", line 9, in <module>
from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._rust import exceptions as rust_exceptions
pyo3_runtime.PanicException: Python API call failed
START RequestId: 26d4c295-51f8-4d98-b698-277a3e43336d Version: $LATEST
RequestId: 26d4c295-51f8-4d98-b698-277a3e43336d Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1
Runtime.ExitError
END RequestId: 26d4c295-51f8-4d98-b698-277a3e43336d
REPORT RequestId: 26d4c295-51f8-4d98-b698-277a3e43336d  Duration: 939.93 ms Billed Duration: 940 ms Memory Size: 512 MB
```

I have increased the Memory size to 512 MB and I have created the paramiko layer using Amazon Linux 2 so it wont have any dependencies issue

Connecting to EC2 through Lambda

Answer (score 0):

Another option i would suggest is to use AWS SSM to trigger operations in EC2 from lambda function.

References:
https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/remotely-run-commands-ec2-instance-systems-manager/

https://medium.com/@Electricste/run-shell-commands-on-a-ec2-from-a-lambda-function-108994911064

Comment: I think that is the better option and is next on the list but I want to resolve this issue as well